# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php, string

i'm beginner in php i get this message   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING , how to fix  plz ?

**PHP**

```
<?php if(is_shop())
        echo 
      "<div class="descriptif">"
        '<p class="a1">'Envie de l’authentique foie gras au marc de banyuls ou
          <br> un bon cochon confit miel gingembre et d’autres produits cuisinés par le chef ?! '</p>'
        '<p class="a1">'C’est le moment de vous faire plaisir !'</p>'
        '<p class="a2">'LE TERROIR « <em>MADE IN COTE SAISONS</em> » C’EST BIEN <em>ICI</em> !'</p>'
       '<p class="a3">'Le Chef <em>Nicolas Ventelon</em> vous propose une gamme de produits locaux offrir ou à déguster chez vous !'</p>'
       '<p class="a4">'Livraison en France métropolitaine par la poste entre 48 et 72h'</p>'
        '<p class="a5">'Les commandes sont traitées tous les jours excepté mercredi et jeudi.'</p>'
      "</div>"
      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (note there is only two `'` at the beginning and at the end of `echo`. In between You should use `"` for html attributes like `class="descriptif"` ). Hope this helps.

```
echo
'<div class="descriptif">
<p class="a1">Envie de l’authentique foie gras au marc de banyuls ou
<br> un bon cochon confit miel gingembre et d’autres produits cuisinés par le chef ?! </p>
<p class="a1">C’est le moment de vous faire plaisir !</p>
<p class="a2">LE TERROIR « <em>MADE IN COTE SAISONS</em> » C’EST BIEN    <em>ICI</em> !</p>
<p class="a3">Le Chef <em>Nicolas Ventelon</em> vous propose une gamme    de produits locaux offrir ou à déguster chez vous !</p>
<p class="a4">Livraison en France métropolitaine par la poste entre 48 et 72h</p>
<p class="a5">Les commandes sont traitées tous les jours excepté   mercredi et jeudi.</p>
</div>';
```

Comment: but  for <em> ?  i have style for <em>

Comment: You can add anything inside like `<em class="someclass">Nicolas Ventelon</em>`.

Answer (score 0):

Writing string :

```
echo 'Hello " World';
```

or

```
echo "Hello ' World";
```

**Multiline string**

```
echo 'Hello
World';
```

Or

```
echo 'Hello' .
     'world';
```

In your case you should correct as follow

```
 echo 
      '<div class="descriptif"> 
        <p class="a1">  Envie de l’authentique foie gras au marc de banyuls ou 
          <br> un bon cochon confit miel gingembre et d’autres produits cuisinés par le chef ?! </p>
        <p class="a1">C’est le moment de vous faire plaisir !</p>
        <p class="a2">LE TERROIR « <em>MADE IN COTE SAISONS</em> » C’EST BIEN <em>ICI</em> </p>
       <p class="a3">Le Chef <em>Nicolas Ventelon</em> vous propose une gamme de produits locaux offrir ou à déguster chez vous !</p>
       <p class="a4">Livraison en France métropolitaine par la poste entre 48 et 72h</p>
        <p class="a5">Les commandes sont traitées tous les jours excepté mercredi et jeudi</p>;
      </div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful not to mix single or double quotes
if you open a string with single quote, ensure you don't have single quotes in it or escape it like this \'

in your code

```
"<div class="descriptif">"
```

you should either enclose 'descriptif' in single quotes or escape it with slash. or use single quotes like

```
'<div class="descriptif">'
```

you should also concatenate strings with dot, i.e.

```
'<div class="descriptif">'.'<p class="a1">'
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a mess between " and ', here is your template fixed :

```
<?php if(is_shop())
    echo 
  '<div class="descriptif">
    <p class="a1">Envie de l’authentique foie gras au marc de banyuls ou
      <br> un bon cochon confit miel gingembre et d’autres produits cuisinés par le chef ?! </p>
    <p class="a1">C’est le moment de vous faire plaisir !</p>
    <p class="a2">LE TERROIR « <em>MADE IN COTE SAISONS</em> » C’EST BIEN <em>ICI</em> !</p>
   <p class="a3">Le Chef <em>Nicolas Ventelon</em> vous propose une gamme de produits locaux offrir ou à déguster chez vous !</p>
   <p class="a4">Livraison en France métropolitaine par la poste entre 48 et 72h</p>
   <p class="a5">Les commandes sont traitées tous les jours excepté mercredi et jeudi.</p>
  </div>';
  ?>
```

This documentation may help you : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: but for <em> ? i have style for <em>